# Trouble with User Authentication Persistence on AWS Amplify After Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js, aws-amplify

I have an async function userAuthenticated() that checks if the user is logged in locally, and it works fine on the AWS Amplify pull request. However, when I refresh the page, it tells me that I'm not logged in. What could be the issue?

```
async function userAuthenticated() {
  try {
    const authenticatedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    return true
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}
```

When I refresh the page, I would expect the user authentication state to remain intact if everything is functioning as intended. In my current situation, with the userAuthenticated() function, it's telling me that I'm not logged in after a page refresh, which is not what I expected. I'm looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue so that user authentication persists correctly even after a page refresh in my AWS Amplify application.

Comment: I solved it by adding the aws amplify configuration
 `cookieStorage: {
       domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN ?? 'localhost',
       secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'
     }`